# Android - Exoplayer not playing offline download after toggling wifi

Tags: android, http-live-streaming, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

If I start my app with wifi off, offline downloaded videos play fine.

But after toggling wifi (on, then off), I get a black screen when watching the same video now. Only error message:

```
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Source error.
```

Has anyone encountered something similar?

Code for how I get the MediaSource:

```
SimpleCache sc = ...
DefaultDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(app, "exoplayer-test");
DefaultExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory().setConstantBitrateSeekingEnabled(true);
CacheDataSourceFactory cacheDataSourceFactory = new CacheDataSourceFactory(sc, dataSourceFactory, CacheDataSource.FLAG_BLOCK_ON_CACHE);
MediaSource mediaSource = new HlsMediaSource.Factory(cacheDataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(uri);
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be fixed when I set the PlaylistParserFactory

```
mediaSource = new HlsMediaSource.Factory(cacheDataSourceFactory)
    .setPlaylistParserFactory(
        new FilteringHlsPlaylistParserFactory(
            new DefaultHlsPlaylistParserFactory(),
            Collections.singletonList(new StreamKey(HlsMasterPlaylist.GROUP_INDEX_VARIANT, 0))))
    .createMediaSource(uri);
```

I followed the instructions here https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/source/hls/offline/HlsDownloader.html to download the original video